# Is there a way to search for extracted features using python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp

I have used td-idf vectorisation to extract features in a text classification problem and now I want to search for specific extracted features. Is there a way to develop a search functionality using python or any other tool for those extracted features? I have used facebook fasttext for out of vocabulary support and td-idf for feature extraction. then feature union is used in the pipeline. Now I want to search for these features(specific to one vector or in whole vector. so is there an option to do so? Here is the code I have used for feature extraction. Thanks

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

alltext = pd.concat([training_set.scrape_text, test_set.scrape_text])
alltext.shape

rows = []
for row in alltext.values:
    rows.append(word_tokenize(row))

model = gensim.models.FastText(rows, size=100, window=4, min_count=2, iter=10)
#NLP pipeline
import re

from nltk.stem import SnowballStemmer

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from collections import defaultdict


class TfidfEmbeddingVectorizer(object):

    def __preprocess(self, row):
        #print("TfidfEmbeddingVectorizer  __preprocess begin")
        cleanr = re.compile('<.*?>')
        cleantext = re.sub(cleanr, ' ', str(row))


        cleaned = cleantext.replace("\n"," ").strip()

        alpha_sent = ""

        for word in cleaned.split():
            alpha_word = re.sub('[^a-z A-Z]+', ' ', word)
            alpha_sent += self.stemmer.stem(alpha_word)
            #alpha_sent += lemmatizer.lemmatize(alpha_word)
            alpha_sent += " "
        alpha_sent = alpha_sent.strip()
        return alpha_sent



    def __tokenize(self, row):
        return word_tokenize(row)

    def __init__(self, model):

        self.model = model
        self.model2weight = None
        self.dim = model.vector_size
        self.stemmer = SnowballStemmer("english")


    def fit(self, X, y):
        print("TfidfEmbeddingVectorizer  fit begin")
        tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer=lambda x: x)

        preprocessed_X = []
        for row in X:
            preprocessed_X.append(self.__tokenize(self.__preprocess(row)))

        preprocessed_X = np.array(preprocessed_X)


        tfidf.fit(preprocessed_X)

        max_idf = max(tfidf.idf_)
        self.model2weight = defaultdict(
            lambda: max_idf,
            [(w, tfidf.idf_[i]) for w, i in tfidf.vocabulary_.items()])
        print("TfidfEmbeddingVectorizer  fit end")

        return self

    def transform(self, X):


        preprocessed_X = []
        for row in X:
            preprocessed_X.append(self.__tokenize(self.__preprocess(row)))

        preprocessed_X = np.array(preprocessed_X)

        return np.array([
                np.mean([self.model[w] * self.model2weight[w]
                         for w in words if w in self.model], axis=0)
                for words in preprocessed_X
            ])


from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, classification_report, confusion_matrix
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion

from xgboost import XGBClassifier

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier, ExtraTreesClassifier, GradientBoostingClassifier, VotingClassifier


pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('feats', FeatureUnion([

        ('vec', TfidfVectorizer(preprocessor=preprocessor, 
                                tokenizer=word_tokenize,
                                analyzer='word', 
                                lowercase=True,
                                strip_accents='unicode',
                                stop_words='english',
                                ngram_range=(1,2)
                               ))

    ])),

    ('voting', VotingClassifier(estimators=[("rf1", RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=1)),
                                        ("gb", GradientBoostingClassifier()),
                                         ("et", ExtraTreesClassifier(n_jobs=1)),
                                         ("xgb",XGBClassifier(nthread= 4, learning_rate=0.08, n_estimators=1000, max_depth=10))
                                       ], 
                                voting='soft',

])
```

Comment: Can you give some example?

Comment: What do you call a feature? One number on the tf-idf vector? The whole vector?

Comment: @Patel I have added the code for your reference. Please have a look and suggest if a search functionality can be developed. Thanks

Comment: @Jindřich the question I had in mind was to search for a specific feature from the entire vocabulary. So a feature can be a number on the td-idf vector. So from the collection of whole vectors if I need to search for one number how it can be done.